# Very advanced exercises and workouts using only resistance bands

Tags: exercise, workout, strength, books

I am looking for **very advanced, intense** workouts or collections of exercises using only a resistance band.

I am primarily interested in free online resources with good pictures or videos. However suggestions for printed books would be interesting, too.

You may say that this is a kind of google question, however I searched the web for hours and didn't find good references. So I think it would be a good idea to collect here some good references on that topic - perhaps this question should be community wiki.

Comment: What would be the goal this workout has in mind, because some might focus on high reps others on high intensity or something. Other than that I agree this can be very useful, especially for those who can't go to a gym for instance.

Comment: [The Great Stretch Tubing Handbook](http://www.amazon.com/Great-Stretch-Tubing-Handbook/dp/0969677367) is probably pretty good. I have some other books from this series, and they're full of usable exercises. It looks like you need something to attach the resistance band to in exercises from this book though, so it wouldn't work if you literally want to use _only_ a resistance band.

Comment: I found a lot on YouTube, but maybe you are looking for things that are more advanced than what's there.

Comment: I like Paul Katami's Band Camp DVD. It has a male instructor and the routines aren't complicated such that I feel 'silly' doing them in front of others. It can be intense if I increase the reps.

Answer (score 2):

[BodyLastics](http://www.bodylastics.com/exercises/) has a great set of exercises including video - I ordered their product and have been very happy with it (I alternate using it every few weeks to break up my routine).  Take a look at their sport specific routines for a complete set of exercises to do.